# How to import mediawiki dump to new namespace

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediawiki page dump from server A and I want to import page dump to another mediawiki Server B with new namespace. Could anyone help me on this

Thanks,

Saravanan

Answer (score 1):

A dump file is an XML document with a simple schema (see [Help:Export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Export)), you just need to rewrite the titles in it.